# JavaScript function driving CPU utilization to 100%

Tags: javascript

I have a series of images which graph temperature, humidity, etc. The image file names do not change, but the images themselves update every 5 minutes. I would like to refresh the images without having to reload the entire page.

The function below accomplishes this, but after a few cycles the processor utilization jumps to 100%. I have commented out all other content on the page so I'm positive that the attempt to refresh the images using the JavaScript function is the cause.

I'm new to JavaScript and don't understand why this is happening nor how to troubleshoot it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function dispGraphs() {

    document.getElementById("tempChart").src="images/tempInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("humChart").src="images/humidityInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("presChart").src="images/pressureInside.png?t=" + Math.random(); 
    document.getElementById("lightChart").src="images/light.png?t=" + Math.random(); 

    setInterval(dispGraphs, 300000);    
}
```

This function is invoked by:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', dispGraphs);
    </script>
```

Comment: Your function creates an interval timer that calls the same function every five minutes. Each time interval time expires, *another* interval timer is set up. That's a pretty long interval, but after a while there will be many of them.

Comment: You probably meant to use setTimeout(...) rather than setInterval(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `setTimeout` insead of `setInterval`.

```
function dispGraphs() {

    document.getElementById("tempChart").src="images/tempInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("humChart").src="images/humidityInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("presChart").src="images/pressureInside.png?t=" + Math.random(); 
    document.getElementById("lightChart").src="images/light.png?t=" + Math.random(); 

    setTimeout(dispGraphs, 300000);    
}
```

The `CPU` gets to 100% because each time the `dispGraphs` function is called a new interval is created that calls this function every 5minutes. So after 5minutes you will have 2 intervals (the interval created at the first call and the interval created after 5 minutes), after 10minutes you will have 4 intervals, each calling the function once every 5 minute. So the number of intervals is exponential to the time passed `nrIntervals = 2 ^ (minutesPassed/5)` (or something similar).

Using `setTimeout` you can be sure that your function will only be called once every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

That one shoul not be inside the function, but outside.

```
setInterval(dispGraphs, 300000);
```

With each cycle you call it again and you end with infinite number of calls to the function `dispGraphs`

Comment: Using `setTimeout` would be a better solution, it's not recommended to use `setInterval`. http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful

Answer (score 0):

```
function dispGraphs() {
  setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("tempChart").src="images/tempInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("humChart").src="images/humidityInside.png?t=" + Math.random();    
    document.getElementById("presChart").src="images/pressureInside.png?t=" + Math.random(); 
    document.getElementById("lightChart").src="images/light.png?t=" + Math.random(); 
  }, 300000);
}
```